# Role of dam methylase in bacteria

Tags: bacteriology, dna-replication

In bacteria, an enzyme called dam methylase (Deoxyadenosine methylase)  methylates adenines (A) in the sequence GATC in the new strand formed after replication. 
What role does this methylation play?
I read that it has something to do with proofreading. If this is so, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dam methylase has three different functions:

1. Correction replication errors, since the new DNA molecule
   is only hemimethylated (the old strand is methylated, the newly
   synthesized is not). Since the proof-reading only takes place on the
   new strand, errors introduced during replication can be corrected.
2. Regulation of replication: The ori of the chromosome is methylated to ensure that is only replicated once.
3. Regulation of transcription: Methylation of GATC sequences promote the transcription of genes.

For further details see the references.

References:

1. [The great GATC: DNA methylation in E. coli](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168952589900541)
2. [The dam and dcm strains of Escherichia coli--a review.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8200522)
3. [Dam methylation: coordinating cellular processes.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15802246)